# WIA Skip device selection dialog while scanning

Tags: delphi, windows-7, com, delphi-xe2, wia

I'm working with WIA 2.0 with Delphi XE2. Right now, I'm attempting to get a scanner to scan. At first I was using `CommonDialog.ShowAcquireImage` which was working fine, except for one thing. I would like to be able to pass in an `IDevice`, an `IDeviceInfo`, or the `DeviceId` in order to skip the device selection dialog. I've tried enumerating through the `Commands` property of the `IDevice`, but all I get is Synchonize and Build Device Tree. Neither of those two commands seems to be what I'm looking for.

I'm trying to avoid this dialog box

[image: Selection Dialog Box]

But still show this dialog box

[image: Properties dialog box].

I've been able to get close two ways. The first is to just use the `ShowTransfer` method of `ICommonDialog`

```
procedure TForm1.btnAutoScanClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  lDevice : IDevice;
  lImage : IImageFile;
  lCommonDialog : ICommonDialog;
begin
  lDevice := fDeviceManager.DeviceInfos[1].Connect;
  lCommonDialog := CoCommonDialog.Create;
  lCommonDialog.ShowDeviceProperties(lDevice,false);
  lImage := IUnknown(lCommonDialog.ShowTransfer(lDevice.Items[1],'{B96B3CAE-0728-11D3-9D7B-0000F81EF32E}',false)) as IImageFile;
  lImage.SaveFile('c:\testauto.jpg');
end;
```

This causes both dialogs to be skipped over and a progress bar to be shown. This won't work as is because I still need to show the properties dialog box.

The second way I've gotten close is to call `ShowAcquireImage` on an `ICommonDialog`

```
procedure TForm1.btnScanClick(Sender: TObject);
const
  pngFormat = '{B96B3CAF-0728-11D3-9D7B-0000F81EF32E}';
  jpegFormat = '{B96B3CAE-0728-11D3-9D7B-0000F81EF32E}';
var
  lImage : IImageFile;
  lDialog : ICommonDialog;
begin
  lDialog := CoCommonDialog.Create;
  lImage := lDialog.ShowAcquireImage(WIA_TLB.UnspecifiedDeviceType,WIA_TLB.GrayscaleIntent,WIA_TLB.MinimizeSize,
    jpegFormat,false,false,false);
  lImage.SaveFile('c:\testmanual.jpg');
end;
```

which works exactly how I want it **if** there is only one WIA device connected to the computer. The second I plug my camera phone back into the computer I start getting the Select Device dialog box.

My question  is how can I skip the device selection dialog box while scanning regardless of how many devices are connected to the machine but still show the properties dialog box?

Comment: lCommonDialog.ShowDeviceProperties(lDevice,false);

comment this line, and you will ok.

Comment: Can you figure out this? I have same problem with ShowAcquireImage method.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried using WIA_TLB.ScannerDeviceType (=1) instead of UnspecifiedDeviceType (=0)?

```
lDialog.ShowAcquireImage(WIA_TLB.ScannerDeviceType,WIA_TLB.GrayscaleIntent,WIA_TLB.MinimizeSize,
           jpegFormat,false,false,false);
```

found @ :
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms630829(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: The problem with that is if I have multiple scanners that support WIA then it's still going to show the device selection dialog. I'm trying to avoid that all together since I have my own device selection mechanism.